# to the contrary or the contrary

Tags: phrase-usage

Is the preposition *to* correct in the following? I'd have expected either no "to" or "anything" in front of "to."

> Until he hears [to] the contrary, he said, he is going ahead as planned, his first show, the Print Fair, opening on Nov. 1.

Comment: _Hears to the contrary_ has the implied meaning _hears information to the contrary_ - that is, that the show cannot take place.

Comment: Is the *to* optional?

Comment: I don't think it is optional in this context. See [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hears+the+contrary%2C+hears+to+the+contrary&year_start=1800&y). I would understand _hears the contrary_ to mean _hears the opposite to a fact or idea that has just been mentioned_.

Comment: I don't understand the difference.

Comment: One of the examples supplied is _Neither was Bismarck a militarist, often as one hears the contrary_ (one often hears that he _was_ a militarist). I see that as different from _I will assume it's going ahead unless I hear to the contrary_ (I later receive information that the event cannot happen).

Comment: I think the difference between "hears the contrary" and "hears to the contrary" is that the former refers to a specific statement contradicting, while the latter could be something more general or vague from which you could infer. For instance, if you assume you're going to the beach with your friend Paul, but then hear Paul is going to the city, that would be hearing something to the contrary, rather than hearing the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Kate, the cited example includes an implied *noun phrase* (such as ***information***). In such contexts *(to hear [**something which is**] to the contrary),* the preposition is always ***to***, and the adverbial element modifies the primary verb (***hear*** in this case) for which that noun phrase is the direct object...

[image]

Alternatively, the adverbial element *[preposition] **the contrary*** may be a "whole sentence adverb" modifying a preceding sentence (or independent clause withing the *current* sentence). An easy way to pick that context out is to [include the contrastive conjunction ***but***...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=but%20to%20the%20contrary%2Cbut%20on%20the%20contrary&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbut%20to%20the%20contrary%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbut%20on%20the%20contrary%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

...where as you can see, the preferred preposition switches decisively to ***on***.